# Canvas context drawing frame rate too fast

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to display a scrolling home screen for an Asteroids game that keeps redrawing the background until the user presses 'enter', after which, it will execute methods necessary to start the game.

The frame rate is normal on the home screen, but when you press enter, the game renders, but moves so fast the animation lags and the game is unplayable.

I feel it must have something to do with the 'speed' variable being out of control, but I have tried resetting it.

If you remove the first call of `requestAnimationFrame`, the home screen will not scroll, (obviously, because the 'speed' never increases, so the background is static), but the game will play at it's normal frame rate. I have also tried calling `this.game.draw(this.ctx, speed)` with `speed` as 0, but to no avail.

Note that `DIM_Y` and `DIM_X` are just constants defined out of scope.

```
GameView.prototype.animate = function(time) {

    speed += 1;
    if (speed >= 605) {
      speed = 0;
    };

  if (this.onHomeScreen) {

    console.log("asf")

    let that = this;
    img.onload = function () {
      that.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
    };

    img.src = 'space_background.png';
    let y = 0;
    let x = 0;
    y += speed;
    this.ctx.drawImage(img, x,y);
    this.ctx.drawImage(img, x, y - DIM_Y);

    if (y >= DIM_Y) {
      y = 0;
    };

    this.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    this.ctx.font = "italic "+24+"pt Arial";
    this.ctx.fillText('ASTEROIDS', 100, 200);
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
    key('enter', ()=> {
      this.onHomeScreen = false;
      this.start();
    });

  } else {
   // 'enter' has been pressed, the game begins.
    this.game.step();
    this.game.draw(this.ctx, speed);
    if(!this.game.lose() && !this.game.win()){ 
      requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
    }
    else {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    this.ctx.font = "italic "+24+"pt Arial ";
    that = this;
      if(this.game.win()){
        that.ctx.fillText(`You Win! \n Press Enter to restart`, 100, 200);
      } else {
        console.log(speed)
        that.ctx.fillText(`Game Over \n Press Enter to restart`, 100, 200);
      }
      key('enter', ()=>{
        this.game = new Game();
        this.start();
      });
    }

  }

};
```

Comment: Just a guess since I don't know how is written `key`, but it could be because you are attaching a key event handler in a loop, so when this event will fire, its callback will be called as many times it was attached (probably a lot in your case). And since the callback does start a new loop, you actually have a lot of loops being started on a single key press, your `speed` variable will be incremented a lot of times and all you do in your loop will be executed a lot of times too.

Comment: @Kaiido That sound plausible, how would you recommend re-writing the callback to key?

Comment: Create an init function where you do load your image, and attach your event which will just trigger the onHomeScreen boolean.